# Monit and Varnish

Tags: varnish, monit

I am using the following config for monit

```
set daemon  30

check process varnish with pidfile /var/run/varnishd.pid
  if failed host www.hatchedbyyolk.com port 80 protocol http
  and request "/monit-check-url"
  then exec "/root/scripts/varnish_restart.sh"

set httpd port 2812 and
use address localhost                            
allow localhost
```

monit starts just fine, but `monit status` shows the following

```
Process 'varnish'
  status                            Does not exist
  monitoring status                 monitored
  data collected                    Sun Oct 13 00:37:03 2013
```

For some unknown reason the start and stop commands have no effect on varnish so I use this script which is in `/root/scripts/varnish_restart.sh`

```
#! /bin/sh
killall varnishd
varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,1G -a 0.0.0.0:80
```

Needless to say something is wrong and Varnish does not restart itself.

What does "Does not exist" mean in this context for the status?

Have I missed something?

**EDIT**

I have just checked too that the PID in the /var/run/varnish.pid file does not match any PID I can see in `top`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PID file won't match the running process since you aren't using the init script - it's not being written to on the service's start.

For the PID file to be updated, you should add `-P /var/run/varnish.pid` to your `varnishd` command line -- or better, figure out why the init script isn't working and fix it.

Comment: that has worked perfectly. Now on to the overarching issue. Any ideas on why Varnish's init may not work for me?

Comment: @jakenoble Good question.  On the RHEL init script I had some problems with it suppressing errors by sending output to `/dev/null` - take a look for something like that in your init script and comment it out, then see if you get any better output?